# Read env variable with unescaped characters from file on ubuntu with bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

How to read environmental variable in bash that contains spaces and possibly other characters that need to be escaped?

I have a file server.env

```
PUBLIC_KEY=ssh-rsa whatever+whatever+8whatever/whatever+p+whatever user@alans-MacBook-Pro.local
```

I am trying to read this file into bash script as an environmental variable:

```sh
export $(cat server.env | xargs)
```

I am getting an error:

```
-bash: export: `user@alans-MacBook-Pro.local': not a valid identifier
```

OK, trying to quote the value in server.env:

```
PUBLIC_KEY='ssh-rsa whatever+whatever+8whatever/whatever+p+whatever user@alans-MacBook-Pro.local'
```

- the same error

Double quote:

```
PUBLIC_KEY="ssh-rsa whatever+whatever+8whatever/whatever+p+whatever user@alans-MacBook-Pro.local"
```

- also errors

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash provides *parameter expansion with substring removal* that will allow you to separate the `NAME=value` pairs read from the `server.env` file and then `export` the `NAME=value` pairs.

A simple read loop is all you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do              ## read each line of server.env
    val="${line#*=}"                ## trim to 1st =, save in val
    export ${line%=$val}="$val"     ## remove =$val leaving name, export val with name
done < server.env

printf "%s\n" "$PUBLIC_KEY"         ## confirm
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash test.sh
ssh-rsa whatever+whatever+8whatever/whatever+p+whatever user@alans-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Where the basic *Parameter Expansions* are:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

(**note:** `pattern` can contain normal shell globs like `'*'` and `'?'`)

There are literally dozens of useful parameter expansions you can use for string manipulations. Just check `man bash` under the `"Parameter Expansion"` heading.

Comment: Minor point, `%=$val` may fail if `val` contains metacharacters. Run `line='a=b[cd]e' val=${line#*=}; echo ${line%=$val}` and you'll see. It should be `%="$val"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL ANSWER (does not `export`, so the variable is not available in subsequent runs of bash, only in the current session):

```
source server.env
```

Comment: Since the file doesn't contain `export`, just the variables, you'll still have to loop through, as explained above.

Comment: If `server.env` is the file with the assignments, and the assignments are still unquoted, they will continue to be syntax errors (or something a lot more sinister, i.e. run commands you did not intend to run).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that field splitting still occurs on the whitespace.

You should do this:

```
export "$(cat server.env)"
```

(i.e. add double quotes).

For multiple variables, loop over the lines:

```
while read -r line
do
    export "$line"
done < server.env
```

If this is in a script called `export.sh`, then you will also want to `source` it for the variables to be set in the current process:

```
source export.sh
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, it sets SSH_KEY to `ssh-rsa` and assigns the rest to the next env variable in file, messing things up

Comment: Does the file contain multiple variables that should each be exported?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying this

Comment: Well don't do it in one go, loop over the lines.