# Delete Last String (Unix Shell Script)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to delete the last string from a Linux/Unix variable containing multiple strings with space separation -

```
strings='Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL EXCEL'
```

I want to delete  the last string i.e. **EXCEL**

**Expected Output -**

```
Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

**Other Input Set -**

```
str1='RUB 20210607 SPREAD'
str2='RUSSIA NULL NULL NULL 20210607 Y Y Y N N Y Y HTML'
str3='LONDON NULL NULL NULL 20210607 Y Y Y N N Y Y CSV'
```

*PS - Here string is trailing sequence of non-space characters.*

Comment: "string" is ambiguous here. I assume you mean the trailing sequence of non-space characters.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65867813/3422102) showing the 4 primary parameter expansions with substring removal available in Unix shell.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, Parameter Expansion with Substring Removal is helpful for this, I was not aware about it earlier.

Comment: @chepner - Yes, your assumption is correct. Have updated it in main question definition also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell can remove or substritute leading or trailing patterns.

```sh
strings='Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL EXCEL'
echo "${strings% *}"
```

prints

```
Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

You need the `echo` command only if you want to print the resulting value. Of course you can use `${strings% *}` in the same way as you could use variable expansion, e.g. `somecommand $strings` vs. `somecommand ${strings% *}` or `somecommand "$strings"` vs. `somecommand "${strings% *}"`, depending on your needs.

Citing https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

> `${parameter%word}`
> **Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern**. The *word* shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in *parameter*, with the smallest portion of the suffix matched by the *pattern* deleted.

Comment: Thank You, This is what I was looking for, This has solved the problem. Also the link shared is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hello  you can try  with `awk` with the  follwing command:

```
strings='Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL EXCEL'
awk '{$NF="";print}' <<< "$strings"
```

Output

Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it by making the field separator to " EXCEL".

```sh
awk -F " EXCEL" '{print $1}' <<< "$strings"
```

Output is

```sh
Y NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20210607 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

**Edit after clarification from op**

Below will work but there are better methods in this thread than my solution. Posting this for some variety.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" ";}{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)print $((i));}END{print "\n"}'
```

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate your thought process, However the solutions should be more generic, this solution is more specific.
As we can have data like -
`RUB 20210607 SPREAD
RUSSIA NULL NULL NULL 20210607 Y Y Y N N Y Y HTML
LONDON NULL NULL NULL 20210607 Y Y Y N N Y Y CSV
`

Comment: @sumitaccess007 Edited my answer and added a method.

Comment: Thank you for making it more generic